# How to save data in the form of Mongodb Nested schema using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to structure mongodb in such a way that it store data in following way.

```js
{
 "question" : "Was today's decision right?",
 "choices" : [
  {
   "text" : "yes",
   "votes" : [
    {
     "ip" : "123.123.123.123",
     "time" : "123444"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "text" : "no",
   "votes" : [
    {
     "ip" : "123.123.123.123",
     "time" : "123444"
    },
    {
     "ip" : "123.123.123.123",
     "time" : "123444"
    },
    {
     "ip" : "123.123.123.123",
     "time" : "123444"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
},
{
 "question" : "Was yesterday's decision right?",
 "choices" : [
  {
   "text" : "yes",
   "votes" : [
    {
     "ip" : "123.123.123.123",
     "time" : "123444"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "text" : "no",
   "votes" : [
    {
     "ip" : "123.123.123.123",
     "time" : "123444"
    },
    {
     "ip" : "123.123.123.123",
     "time" : "123444"
    },
    {
     "ip" : "123.123.123.123",
     "time" : "123444"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

What i have done so far for structure after little searching

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var voteSchema = new Schema({
 ip: String
});

var choiceSchema = new Schema({
 text: String,
    votes: [voteSchema]
});

var PollSchema = new Schema({
 question: { type: String, required: true },
 choices: [choiceSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Polls', PollSchema);
```

Now if I use following code to save hard coded data then it's working fine

```js
var poll = new Poll({
        question : reqBody.question,
  choices : [
   {
    text : "yes",
    votes : [
     {
      ip : "123.123.123.123"
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    text : "no",
    votes : [
     {
      ip : "123.123.123.123",
     },
     {
      ip : "123.123.123.123",
     },
     {
      ip : "123.123.123.123",
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
    });

 poll.save(function(err, data) {
        res.json(data);
    });
```

But i am not able to figure how i should send data from front end (html/js)?

Comment: you can simply do let poll = new require("yourSchema,js"); and then poll.save(callback);

Comment: Actually i am able to figure out how . My code is working fine with hard coded data

Comment: well, whats your question though?

Comment: Updated question, if that can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got solution :**

First put the following code in controller file

```js
 var reqBody = req.body;
 var choices = reqBody.choices;
 var choicesnew = [];
 for (var i = choices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var votes = [];
  var choice = {text:choices[i],votes: votes};
  choicesnew.push(choice);
 }
 var newPoll = {
  question: reqBody.question,
  choices: choicesnew
 }
 var poll = new Poll(newPoll);
 poll.save(function(err, data){
  res.json(reqBody);
 });
```

And now pass the data using front end

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="question">
  <input type="text" name="choices" placeholder="choices">
  <input type="text" name="choices" placeholder="choices">
  <input type="text" name="choices" placeholder="choices">
  <input type="text" name="ip" placeholder="ip">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Although some data should be processed by nodejs. I am just listing here just for the sake of simplicity.

Now i am using ajax to send data from front end to node

```js
$("form").on('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
    url: '/new',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(this).serializeArray(),
   })
   .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
   })
   .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
   })
   .always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
   });
   
  });
```